# Simple breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

I have this code of a breadcrumb that I found, but it shows the whole link. How can I make a similar simple breadcrumb that shows only the name of the page based on the path? (only in JavaScript)
(it would be good to change the background color too)

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> / ";
}
i=s.length-1;
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + path;
document.writeln(url);

</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean with name of the page?

Comment: The title, you know like:
Home>Products>paint>red
Not like:
http://www.javascriptkit.com / script / script2 / breadcrumb.shtml
as it is now

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that it will not include the site in the breadcrumbs??

```
<script language="Text/JavaScript">


var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
  path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+(i == 2 ? "home" : s[i])+"</A> / ";
}
i = s.length-1;
path += "<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url = path;
document.writeln(url);

</script>
```

Comment: No right now it shows:
http://www.javascriptkit.com / script / script2 / breadcrumb.shtml 
But I want it to be like (with hyperlinks):
Home/script/script2/breadcrumb

Comment: do you mean to replace the "javascriptkit.com" to "Home"? if so, i updated the example above.

Comment: Well not exactly home, it was just an example. I want to show the title of the recent pages that you have been on before, to know where you are and have been. It doesn't show anything when I copy-paste your code.

Comment: In my answer I replaced the string in `i=2` to "home" just replace it to the string that you need

Comment: Ah okay, but do you think it could be automatic? When you create the page you usually give it an title/name. Could you take that name automatically instead of writing it manually?
And how do I delete the "https://"

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax :P
How do you implement that to the navigation?

Comment: You need to create a function that will return to you the title. And put it it where I wrote "Home"

Comment: How do I do that?